# How to use ScrollView with third party Components in React Native?

Tags: node.js, react-native

Very simple, how can I use ScrollView when using an third party (react-native-elements) List/List-Items? The given docs does not inform this: [link](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/lists.html)

The list is fully working, but can't be scrolled:

[image]

Here is the code for rendering the list:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <List>
        {
            list.map((l, i) => (
                <ListItem
                    roundAvatar
                    key={i}
                    title={l.name}
                    subtitle={
                        <View>
                            <View style={styles.subtitleView}>
                                <Text style={styles.ratingText}>{l.subtitle}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    }
                    avatar={<Avatar
                        medium
                        rounded
                        source={l.avatar_url && { uri: l.avatar_url }}
                        title={l.name[0]}
                    />}
                />
            ))
        }
    </List>
</View>
```

If I simply change the View to ScrollView, that should be the obvious move, I get this error:

[image]

I'm importing ScrollView from native-base and the List from react-native-elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the `ScrollView` under your `View`, also add additional `View` (not required) under the `ScrollView`.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <ScrollView>
   <View>
    <List>
        {
            list.map((l, i) => (
                <ListItem
                    roundAvatar
                    key={i}
                    title={l.name}
                    subtitle={
                        <View>
                            <View style={styles.subtitleView}>
                                <Text style={styles.ratingText}>{l.subtitle}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    }
                    avatar={<Avatar
                        medium
                        rounded
                        source={l.avatar_url && { uri: l.avatar_url }}
                        title={l.name[0]}
                    />}
                />
            ))
        }
    </List>
   </View>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Also consider using FlatList rather than ScrollView for better performance.

Reference:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Comment: Omg... This was the worst mistake actually, I was importing from native-base instead of react-native, when I saw react-native in the URL I changed the import and worked... I'll try to do it using the FlatList as suggested, gonna give you the correct answer either way. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't get FlatList to work with the current render code, tried using list.map as renderItem as well but no luck.